# GitLab CI doesn't get Matlab started

Tags: matlab, gitlab

I have a big Matlab project repository in GitLab, and am setting up some automated testing in GitLab CI.  Alas, when I push, while it does kick off a new pipeline and start my batch file, it doesn't seem to get an instance of Matlab running, so the process gets stuck indefinitely.  (the runner is on a windows machine)

First, the .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - cd
  - cd testing
  - cd

main_test:
  stage: test
  script: run_unit_tests.bat
```

Nice and simple.
Next, the batch file:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mytime=%time%
echo ..
echo Current time is %mydate%:%mytime%


echo ..
echo %ERRORLEVEL%

matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile "automatic_tests_log.txt" -r "run('run_main_unit_testing.m')"

echo ..
type "automatic_tests_log.txt"
echo ..
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

(The %ERRORLEVEL% checks are there to help track some troubles getting a non-zero error code out.  But that's solved now.)

And the results:
The pipeline fires up and starts fine.  After it reports the three cd commands, then we get:

```
$ run_unit_tests.bat
..
Current time is 10/12/2018:20:03:39.18
..
0
. . .
```

with that last elipses being the GitLab "in progress" animation.  Basically, it never gets Matlab started; it gets stuck waiting for the matlab command in my batch script.  (I've waited up to 30 minutes.  This process is slow, but not that slow.)  When I run the same batch script directly from the command line, it works fine, and takes about 1-2 minutes.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **exit** matlab:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile "automatic_tests_log.txt" -r "run('run_main_unit_testing.m'); exit"
```